# how to design user info if Legal

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, modeling

I am desinging a user table . In my project User can `Legal` or `Real`.
If user Is `Legal` has some propperty and should fill it Like : `Company name , Company Phone` ...

for design it , I have two solution :

**way 1:**  Put All Fields in a User Table Like this :

[image]

**Way 2:** create another table like `UserLegal` and create a Relation between this and `User` Table (one to one).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real User and Legal User are subclasses (or, if you prefer, subtypes) of User.
Modeling subclasses in a relational model, and implementing the model in  SQL tables is often baffling to database newcomers.

Take a look at the following tags:  [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)

The questions and answers grouped under these tags will show you some other examples.  The info tabs will give you an overview of the two designs.  That will pretty much confirm what you started out with, but there's a little more material in there.